# Is there a better solution? Receiving "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

Tags: r

This is my example.

```
user_id <- sample(seq(1,100),5000, TRUE)
friend_id <- sample(seq(1,100),5000, TRUE)
friends <- data.frame(user_id, friend_id) 
friends <- friends %>% 
  filter(!user_id == friend_id)
friends <- friends %>% arrange(user_id) %>% distinct()

user_id <- sample(seq(1,100),10000, TRUE)
page_id <- sample(seq(1000,2000),10000, TRUE)
pages <-  data.frame(user_id, page_id)
pages <- arrange(pages, user_id) %>% distinct()

popular <- friends %>%
  left_join(pages, by = c("friend_id" = "user_id")) %>%
  group_by(user_id, page_id) %>%
  summarize(likes = n()) %>%
  arrange(-likes) %>%
  filter(!page_id %in% pages[pages$user_id == user_id,]$page_id)
```

My goal is to count the number of likes for each of the pages that a user's friend has liked. The last step is giving me this warning:

> 50: In pages$user_id == user_id :   longer object length is not a
>   multiple of shorter object length

My goal in the last step is to filter out any page that the user has liked.

1) If I group by a column and then apply filter, will it apply to each of the grouped data frames separately? In other words, is it like having a for loop that says `for (group in tbl) apply filter`?

2) Will `user_id` give me the `user_id` according to each group? I guess this is an extension of 1.

3) I think it gives me the warning since `pages$user_id` is long and `user_id` is just one value. Is there a better solution or a more appropriate solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
pages_agg <- pages %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  summarise(likes = n()) 

left_join(friends, pages_agg, by = c("friend_id" = "user_id")) %>%
  head()
  user_id friend_id likes
1       1        44   107
2       1        76    90
3       1        36   116
4       1         4   110
5       1        57    93
6       1        32    96
```